# C: for loop with two variables and circular shift

Tags: c, for-loop

I could not figure out how the following `for` loop works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, j, n=4;
  for (i = 0, j = n-1; i < n; j = i++)
      printf("\ni: %d, j:%d", i, j);
    
 return 0;
}
```

Which produces:

```
i: 0, j:3
i: 1, j:0
i: 2, j:1
i: 3, j:2
```

The increment rule `j = i++` confuses me. I do not get the circular shift behavior of `j`. Also, there is no increment rule for `i` and it increases by 1. Can someone explain?

Comment: i++ increases i by 1. j=i++ gets the value of i *before* it is increased by 1. Try it on a piece of paper.

Comment: There is no circular behaviour. `j` just lags behind `i` by 1 iteration. The initial value of `3` is not related to that at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop written in that form

```
for(init; cond; incr) { instruction bloc }
```

can be rewritten in that form :

```
init;
while(cond) 
{ 
    instruction bloc;

    incr;
}
```

So you can write your loop another way:

```
int i, j, n=4;

// first parameter of for loop
i = 0;
j = n-1; 

// second parameter of for loop : while the condition is true, stay in instruction bloc
while( i < n) {

    // instruction bloc
    printf("\ni: %d, j:%d", i, j);

    // third parameter: executed after instruction bloc
    j = i++
}
```

Hence you can understand how `i` and `j` are increased:

```
j = i++;
```

Could be rewritten:

```
j = i;
i = i + 1;
```